# Where is X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY coming from on Django site via nginx?

Tags: django, iframe, nginx, http-headers

My Django site uses [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) in iframes, and is throwing this error:

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values
>   ('SAMEORIGIN, DENY') encountered when loading
>   'http://example.com/summernote/editor/id_comment_text/'. Falling back
>   to 'DENY'.

**I can't figure out where the DENY is coming from.**

In my Django project settings I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

which: "[By default, the middleware will set the X-Frame-Options header to SAMEORIGIN for every outgoing HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses)."

I also added this in my nginx.conf (from [here](https://gist.github.com/plentz/6737338)):

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

Other possibly relevant info:  The problem arose when I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, and by project's virtual environment from Python 3.4 to Python 3.5.  The version of Django and django-summernote are still the same.

How do I find the source of this DENY setting?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, @43Tesseracts - did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Yes! nginx was using multiple conf files.  I was only looking at my custom nginx.conf file, but this was being over rode by another conf file.  Sorry I don't remember the specifics and don't have access to the server at the moment.

Comment: If this happens, one must look inside all the relevant nginx config files and check all the add_headers.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the issue was in the file:
/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf

Just had to comment out:
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

Comment: This solved the problem for me aswell. This option overwrites the content in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf